# How to inspect network requests and responses happened in Android System WebView remotely?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

Recently I have a problem in inspecting network requests and responses happened in Android System WebView.

The problem is that our app sometimes failed to load some urls with Android System WebView, but we can not get enough information to trace these cases.

Tools like Fiddler or Charles have some limitations like I should have access to that Android device, right?

And I also tried tools like Chrome Remote Debugging, this tool was amazing to debug problems in Android System WebView, but I should have Android device and development machine connected via USB, right?

So, is there any helpful things for me to inspect network requests and responses happened in Android System WebView remotely?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Use Charles Proxy for inspecting network requests, it is pretty easy to use

this article will help
https://medium.com/@hackupstate/using-charles-proxy-to-debug-android-ssl-traffic-e61fc38760f7

add ssl proxy settings for the domain you want so that you can see the responses and requests clearly with headers and value you are sending in the body or in headers

if you want only remote debugging in chrome for webview

follow this 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Comment: maybe this link help you 
https://remysharp.com/2016/12/17/chrome-remote-debugging-over-wifi

Comment: thank you for your reply, my problem is not how to use Charles Proxy nor Chrome Remote debugging, I simply want to find a way to do packet capture on device without root. Anyway, thank you very much.